# Connection works only after router restart

Tags: wifi, ethernet, connection

My raspberry pi 3 with octopi is connected via Wifi with my router (fritz box).
The pi is connects itself successfully.

I can't access the pi from my computer (i can't even ping) if the computer is connected with ethernet to my router. If the computer is connected via Wifi to the router I can normally access the pi. If I restart the router it's working also over ethernet but only for one day, then I need to restart the router again.

While i can't access the pi from my computer i can access it from any other device connected via Wifi.

Ping from the pi to the computer also fails.

The devices are in the same ip range.

Has someone an idea how to investigate this further?

Comment: some wi-fi router setup can isolate wifi clients - turn that off

Comment: isolation wasn't active. This Issue appears only with the Raspberry Pi. Other devices like Printer/chromecast/smartphones work without any problems.

Comment: It may seem that way superficially, but the issue *must be* the router.  If a ping times out, it indicates either there is no one at that address or there is a firewall configured to drop packets.  If instead it fails immediately (eg., with "unreachable"), it indicates there is a firewall configured to bounce packets.  Presuming there is no such firewall, you are left with one possibility: The ping times out because there is no one at that address, meaning **the ping was never received, therefore the target of the ping cannot be at fault**.  It's a routing issue.

Comment: When the Ethernet drops, check the lights on the port on the router and Pi - then run `ifconfig` and see if that has any valid IP address for the Ethernet port.  If the lights report no connection but the pi has an IP then it's most likely cable or router.  If the lights report connection but no IP on the pi then software is the error would be my guess.

Comment: When the computer is connected wired can you ping from it any other device connected wireless, except the RasPi?